# How to retrieve Corresponding values in array of object on button click in react native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, react-native, object

i am using below code to display each company name with the help of map and Object.entries. So i have used each company name as a button as in below code.
But now my challenge is how can i display id of each button as alert box instead of simple alert button pressed message.
eg when i click on Company 1 button , i want to display id 4 in alert box.

```
  const companyDatas = {
    "accounts": {
        "company 1 ": {
            "id": "4",
            "enabled": "1"
        },
        "company 2": {
            "id": "2",
            "enabled": "1"
        },
        "company 3": {
            "id": "1",
            "enabled": "1"
        }
    }
  };

  const [companyData, setCompanyData] = useState(companyDatas)

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {
        Object.entries(companyData.accounts)
        .map(([company, accountData]) => (
          <View key={company}>

        <Button
           title={company}
           onPress={() => Alert.alert('Simple Button pressed')}
       />
            
          </View>
        ))
      }
    </View>
  );
}
```

OUTPUT

[image]

Comment: Just switch `onPress={() => Alert.alert('Simple Button pressed')}` with `onPress={() => Alert.alert(accountData.id)}`. What exactly are you having difficulties with?

Comment: my issue is i have three different button and each button correspond to particular id. eg when i click on compan 2 button , i need to display only 2, not 4 . how can i achieve that

Answer (score 0):

you used useState from react Library so try a simple way to get it

```
const companyDatas = {
    "accounts": {
        "company 1 ": {
            "id": "4",
            "enabled": "1"
        },
        "company 2": {
            "id": "2",
            "enabled": "1"
        },
        "company 3": {
            "id": "1",
            "enabled": "1"
        }
    }
};

Object.entries(companyDatas.accounts) // Array(2) [["company number", "object" : {"id": INT , "enabled" : INT}]]
    .forEach(([key, value],index) => {

        let companyName = key;
        let companyID = value.id ?? "Company ID does not exist";
        let companyEnabled = value.enabled;
        let company = {};
        company[index] = function () {
            alert(
                `company name :${companyName} \n` +
                `company id :${companyID} \n` +
                `company enabled :${companyEnabled} \n`
            );
        }

        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                {
                    <View key={companyID}>

                        <Button
                            title={companyName}
                            onPress={company[index]()}
                        />

                    </View>

                }
            </View>
        );
    });
```